# WCF extend authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I need to extend built-in WCF authentication, so my new one should work side-by-side with built-in ones.

For instance, I want to allow access from registered IP (custom auth) or with username+password (built-in auth).

I've successfully implemented `ServiceAuthenticationManager` and `ServiceAuthorizationManager`.

`ServiceAuthenticationManager.Authenticate` simply adds `IPrincipal` implementation to message properties, `ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccessCore` copies `IPrincipal` from incoming message properties to `AuthorizationContext` properties.

However, `ServiceAuthenticationManager.Authenticate` is completely broken for standard mechanisms, even if I return `authPolicy` or result of `base.Authenticate` call.

Maybe I went in the wrong direction? What is the correct way to add custom WCF authentication, not affecting existing ones? How to fallback to built-in authentication if custom fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct approach:

Setup ServiceHost in OnOpening override

```
Authorization.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom;
Authorization.ExternalAuthorizationPolicies = new ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy>(new[] { new MyCustomAuthorizationPolicy() });
```

In the Evaluate method of custom policy assign three properties of evaluation context "PrimaryIdentity" to IIdentity, "Identities" to collection of identities and "Principal" to IPrincipal

```
evaluationContext.Properties["PrimaryIdentity"] = identity;
evaluationContext.Properties["Identities"] = new List<IIdentity>(new[] { identity });
evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = principal;
```